# Service fabric only configuration deploy

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Can anyone help to construct deploy package for Service Fabric that only will update configurations for services that are already deployed on SF cluster?

I'm trying to create a differential package that has a structure like this :

1) Application package

a) SerwisXPkg

- Config/Settings.xml

- ServiceManifest.xml

b) SerwisZPkg

- Config/Settings.xml

- ServiceManifest.xml

c) ApplicationManifest.xml

ApplicationTypeVersion version is updated to a higher version than the one that is deployed to SF. Each ServiceManifest.xml version is also updated to higher version. But when I try to update Cluster on SF I receive :
"The application package is invalid. The code is missing for service SerwisXPkg."

Question if I'm doing this correctly ?. Every information that I've found on internet points that this is how it should be done but I must be missing something here

Comment: Why do you want to update only configuration ? Do you have some special restrictions on that you can have only specific version of Application on SF ? Package is smallest unit for deploy on Service Fabric.
There is some solutions like https://www.consul.io/ for "hot" configuration updates, but you should host your app executable under some daemon.

Comment: Which command is failing? Copy, Register or Upgrade? You should be able to use this API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/test-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps) to test the package against a cluster which has the current version registered.